# Share video file in Snapchat through Intent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

Is it possible to share video file from Android app to Snapchat by using intent?
When I try code below, Snapchat is opened but without option to share video file.

```
val file = File(context.cacheDir, filePath)
val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.applicationContext.packageName + ".share", file)

val snapchatIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
snapchatIntent.setType("video/*")
snapchatIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
snapchatIntent.component = ComponentName("com.snapchat.android", "com.snapchat.android.LandingPageActivity")
startActivity(snapchatIntent)
```

I added Provider like this

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.share"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
</provider>
```

And file paths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <cache-path name="image" path="/"/>
    <cache-path name="video" path="/"/>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Comment: First, use a concrete MIME type. Second, there is no requirement for that particular activity to exist, let alone support `ACTION_SEND`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried 
snapchatIntent.type = "video/mp4" 
snapchatIntent.setPackage("com.snapchat.android")
and still nothing. I think I tried everything :(